# Категории и подкатегориии

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Покажите как можно организовать категории и подкатегории. На php и mysql. Создал две таблицы: category и subcategory.

```
category
id
name

subcategory
id
name
```

Материалы в таблице blog

```
blog
id
name
cat_id
```

Вот с категориями все понятно. В cat_id записывается id категории и потом по нему выбирается нужное. А как сделать связь между категорией и подкатегорией к нужному материалу?

Comment: добавить в blog поле sub_cat_id ?

а вообще - как-то не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить.

может расширите свой вопрос примером?

Comment: я хочу понять принцип построения категорий и подкатегорий. понять как их связывать между собой. допустим, я создаю категорию и могу добавить в это категорию подкатегорию. уже потом я добавляю метериал в подкатегорию например. при просмотре материала в url отображается последовательность: категория/подкатегория/ название материала

Comment: @mr-oyvy Зачем Вам сущность `subcategory`? А если для subcategory будет необходимо указать subcategory, т.е. sub-sub-category. Вариант предложенный @Станислав Ельков вполне жизнеспособный.

Comment: решил сделать, как предложил Станислав Ельков))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем примере для начала нужно организовать связи между категориями и подкатегориями. Для этого в таблицу **subcategory** нужно добавить поле **category**, которое будет внешним ключом к таблице **category**.
Ну а затем в таблицу **blog** можно добавить поле **subcat_id**, которое будет хранить подкатегорию.

Но более разумным решением было бы использовать одну таблицу для категорий и организовать её в виде дерева. Поля были бы такими:

> id
>
> parent
>
> name

Поле parent является ссылкой на родительскую категорию. Соответственно у категорий самого верхнего уровня это поле равно 0. При таком подходе мы получаем неограниченную вложенность категорий, подкатегорий, подподкатегорий и т.д.

Comment: вот про дерево я читал, но так и не понял. Получается, нужно сделать одну таблицу, в которой будут создаваться и категории и подкатегории? Тогда определяется, какая подкатегория относится к категории именно по parent?

Comment: посидел подумал, вроде понял, как сделать)

Comment: @Станислав Ельков, одно замечание у рутовой категории, лучше не `0`, а `null`. Так логичнее.